# Have the same height with autoWidth enabled OwlCarousel

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

I want to show a little gallery in my website, but the images are not responsive with the AUTOWIDTH CODE, and they don't have the same height.

I create a JS Fiddle so I can explain my self better.

https://jsfiddle.net/w6axkqmz/1/

I tried using this CSS

```
.gallery .owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    display: flex !important;
}
.gallery .owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

But leave the rectangular images as a square.

Comment: Have you tried using media queries? So that it adjusts for each screen size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Owl Carousel 2 Responsive image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125314/owl-carousel-2-responsive-image)

Answer (score 1):

Do not set `height:50vh` it is going to set the height of every image to 50% of browser's viewport's height. But without setting the height, `object-fit` is not going to work. Set height as `100%` so that it will be of the same height of gallery.

Relative JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2psgqb3v/

---

The reason you need `width` and `height` set is because for browser needs to *fit* the image/object to that height. If you don't specify that, then browser will take image's height/width to render.

---

The solution is to have media query to set the width and height of the images.

Relative fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/74rok0yg/

Comment: I got square thumbnails instead of rectangular ones.

Comment: You will have to go with fixed height then. I'd day 250x250 should be fine.

Comment: thanks for your jsfiddle code, help me to solve this issue.